# I have a website running on local server ... need help making it public

Tags: python, flask

Note: The ip addresses given are not the exact addresses. They are just for examples

I have a website built on flask running on a linux server that is using the internal ip address and a specific port... 192.168.10.10:1001. I know that the works on other computers on the same wifi.

How can I make the ip address public so that I can access the website without the wifi (outside network)? I know my the external ip address of the server... 100.250.250.25.

I have set up port forwarding so that I can 'access' my server from outside the network... 192.168.10.10:1000. I have accessed the server using the port forwarding but again it was on the same network. (Extra Question) Is that enough to access my server outside the network (or even using 100.250.250.25:1000)?

This applies to django as well because I have websites with django that I would like to use my server as well in the future. (Hopefully 192.168.10.10:1002).

Answer (score 1):

You need to deploy your apps in live server like VPS. For the demonstration, you can try Heroku, pythonanywhere. You will find these tutorials available on other sites.